What are the differences for each difficulty level?
Helldivers 2 has ten different difficulties:

Trivial
Easy
Medium
Challenging
Hard
Extreme
Suicide Mission
Impossible
Helldive
Super Helldive

You're not told much about how each difficulty changes the game though.
How does each difficulty level change the game?

There's a lot. I tried making a table, failed, and GalacticNinja fixed it.
For each difficulty, here's what it adds to itself and every higher difficulty (including xp and requisitions bonus):



Difficulty Level
Changes




Trivial+
• +1 mission per operation (excluding blitz, 1 total)• Common samples• Small enemy patrols• Primary objectives


Easy+
• Allied tactical objectives• Light outposts


Medium+
• +1 mission per operation (including blitz, 2 total)• Secondary Objectives (tactical objective marked on map)• Heavily armored enemies• Medium enemy outposts• +25% bonus multiplier to rewards (25% total)


Challenging+
• Rare Samples• Enemy tactical objectives (Terminid Stalker Lairs, Spore Spewers, Automaton Detector Towers, AA Emplacements)• Small enemy patrols upgraded to medium• Heavy Outposts• +25% bonus (50% total)


Hard+
• +1 mission per operation (3 total) • Massive Enemies• +1 operation modifier (poor intel, orbital fluctuations, etc, 1 total)• +25% bonus (75% total)


Extreme+
• More allied and enemy tactical objectives• +25% bonus (100% total)


Suicide Mission+
• Enemy patrols upgraded to large• Super Samples• +50% bonus (150% total)


Impossible+
• Increased enemy numbers• +1 operation modifier (2 total)• +50% bonus (200% total)


Helldive+
• Buffed spawn rate for heavily armored and massive enemies• Increased enemy numbers• +50% bonus (250% total)


Super Helldive
• Super Heavy outposts• Carryables can be found that give samples if extracted



Note: Each tier gives more warbond medals than the last (and so do additional missions).

Proposal: instead of "+200% bonus", which reads like a difference from the previous difficulty, how about something like "sets bonus to 200%"? (Yes I know you called this out in the intro text, but I think it's pretty easy to miss that callout or misunderstand it.)
